# How do I decode a base64 string in MS Word macro?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to decode a base64 string in macro for Word 2016.

I'm using this code but is not working. Did I have to create a function?

```
MsgBox Base64DecodeString("SGVsbG8gc3R1ZGVudHM=")
```

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20060527094535/http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-encode-decode-base64-vb6.asp

Comment: this is the only fully working example I found: https://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/12.htm

Answer (score 2):

The `Base64DecodeString()` you allude to *appears* to have been deprecated a while ago. It looks like you *can,* if you include a reference to the Microsoft XML libraries, do this relatively simply with something like (courtesy of the wayback machine, http://web.archive.org/web/20060527094535/http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-encode-decode-base64-vb6.asp):

```
Private Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = strData
    DecodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

However, I haven't tried that, and it's so dated (May 2006) it mentions VB6. I make *no* guarantees on that code.

---

If you can't use that code for some reason (including the possibility it no longer works), here's a snippet from my own library, which I *can* vouch for, if not actually guarantee :-).

I've fleshed it out with a `Macro1()` test driver subroutine but you should be able to use the `DecodeBase64()` function from anywhere:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private Function GetByte(needle)
    Dim haystack
    haystack = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

    GetByte = InStr(1, haystack, needle, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
    If GetByte = -1 Then
        Err.Raise 513, "DecodeBase64", "Invalid character in base64 string"
    End If
End Function

Private Function DecodeBase64(strData)
    Dim i, inCount, outCount, firstTime
    Dim inArray(0 To 3) As Integer
    Dim outArray() As Byte

    If Len(strData) Mod 4 <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise 514, "DecodeBase64", "Base64 string length is wrong length"
    End If

    Rem Each quartet generates up to three bytes.

    firstTime = True
    While Len(strData) > 0
        Rem Get incoming values (up to "="), counting them.

        inCount = 0
        For i = 1 To 4
            If Mid(strData, i, 1) <> "=" Then
                inArray(i - 1) = GetByte(Mid(strData, i, 1))
                inCount = inCount + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Rem Must have four non-"=" characters unless at end.

        If Len(strData) > 4 And inCount <> 4 Then
            Err.Raise 515, "DecodeBase64", "Base64 string has interal '='"
        End If

        Rem Must have at least two non-"=" characters.

        If inCount < 2 Then
            Err.Raise 516, "DecodeBase64", "Base64 string has invalid ending"
        End If

        Rem Get output bytes based on input (2->1, 3->2, 4->3), expand array.

        outCount = inCount - 1
        If firstTime Then
            ReDim outArray(outCount - 1)
            firstTime = False
        Else
            ReDim Preserve outArray(UBound(outArray) + outCount)
        End If

        Rem Add elements to output.

        outArray(UBound(outArray) + 1 - outCount) = (inArray(0) And &H3F) * 4 + (inArray(1) And &H30) / 16
        If outCount >= 2 Then
            outArray(UBound(outArray) + 2 - outCount) = (inArray(1) And &HF) * 16 + (inArray(2) And &H3C) / 4
        End If
        If outCount >= 3 Then
            outArray(UBound(outArray) + 3 - outCount) = (inArray(2) And &H3) * 64 + (inArray(3) And &H3F)
        End If

        Rem Move to next quartet.

        strData = Mid(strData, 5)
    Wend

    DecodeBase64 = outArray
End Function

Sub Macro1()
    MsgBox StrConv(DecodeBase64("SGVsbG8gc3R1ZGVudHM="), vbUnicode)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function EncodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()
    Dim objXML2 As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    arrData = StrConv(strData, vbFromUnicode)
    '-------------------------------
    Set objXML2 = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML2.createElement("b64")
    '-------------------------------
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    '-------------------------------
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text
    '-------------------------------
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML2 = Nothing
End Function

Private Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()
    Dim objXML2 As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    '-------------------------------
    Set objXML2 = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML2.createElement("b64")
    '-------------------------------
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = strData
    '-------------------------------
    DecodeBase64 = StrConv(objNode.nodeTypedValue, vbUnicode)
    '-------------------------------
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML2 = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: can you give a bit of explanation?